# Compare FxCop TypeNode to System.Type

Tags: c#, types, code-analysis, fxcop, fxcop-customrules

I have an attribute named `SearchableAttribute`, which tags properties of classes. However, only properties of type `string` are allowed to be tagged with this `[Searchable]` attribute. In order to restict it, I am trying to write a CodeAnalysis rule which analyses the properties of my classes, checks for the existence of the `[Searchable]` attribute and creates a `Problem` if the property's type is not `string`.

This is what I have in my Rule class so far:

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member) {
    PropertyNode property = member as PropertyNode;
    if (property == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (property.Attributes.Any(a => a.Type.FullName.Equals((typeof(SearchableAttribute)).FullName)
            && !property.Type.FullName.Equals((typeof(string)).FullName)) {
        Resolution resolution = getResolution(property);
        Problem problem = new Problem(resolution);
        Problems.Add(problem);
    }

    return Problems;
}
```

While this actually does work, I can't believe ... no, I don't *want to* believe that I really have to compare the type's full names. I'm unable to figure out how to properly check for the existence of the `SearchableAttribute` and compare the property's type with string, however. Is there no clean and elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FrameworkTypes.String` should do the trick.

FWIW, there is no real bridge between the framework types and their FxCop `TypeNode`s.  All mappings need to be created based on name, which ideally includes the assembly fully qualified name.  The `FrameworkTypes` properties basically give you shortcuts to accessing such mappings pre-created for you by the FxCop framework.